# jnlp cannot start the swt application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jnlp

I'm trying to run application  via jnlp I'm trying to test the jnlp file locally before trying to deploy my app on some server.  all the swt libs for the correrspondind platforms are selfsigned and  in the same directory withe the jnlp file . additional  jars required by my application jmf.jar and jl1.0.1 are also here.
i'm referencing them as

```
<resources>
    <java version="1.5" />
    <jar href="MyBaran.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="jl1.0.1.jar" download="eager"/>
    <nativelib href="jmf.jar" download ="eager"/>   
</resources>
```

my main application jar(MyBaran.jar)  has the following structure

```
MyBaran.jar  
-com  
--game  
---Main.class  
---Game.class  
...
---Character.class
-images  
--test.jpg  
--sound.wav  
...  
--forrest.mid  
-META-INF  
--MANIFEST.MF  
--...    
-.project  
-.classpath
```

i generated it with eclipse export -> jar file  tools
So my application doesn't start 
on windows java ask the sequrity questions, i accept it  downloads some jars
 here is the ouput from the trace file

```
CacheEntry[file:/H:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/swt-win32-windows-x86.jar]:     updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Mon Feb 04 17:48:22 GMT+03:00 2013,length=2048373  
CacheEntry[file:/H:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/jmf.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Tue Feb 05 10:32:17 GMT+03:00 2013,length=1969383  
CacheEntry[file:/H:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/MyBaran.jar]:   updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Tue Feb 05 13:59:24 GMT+03:00 2013,length=5924842  
CacheEntry[file:/H:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/jl1.0.1.jar]:   updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Tue Feb 05 10:31:30 GMT+03:00 2013,length=112570
```

so it looks like it loads the swt jars
but still  I cannot start my appplication
so should I generate runnable jar file with eclipse with all the libs packaged inside the jar. So how do I write the jnlp file in this case

here is my current jnlp file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<jnlp spec="1.5" href="mybaran.jnlp">  
<information>
    <title>Garbage Collector Game</title>  
    <vendor>Java Tester</vendor>  
    <homepage href="" />  
    <description>Garbage Collector Game</description>  
    <description>Garbage Collector Game</description>   
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>

<resources>
    <java version="1.5" />
    <jar href="MyBaran.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="jl1.0.1.jar" download="eager"/>
    <nativelib href="jmf.jar" download ="eager"/>   
</resources>

<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="swt-win32-windows-x86.jar" />
</resources>

<resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="swt-win32-windows-x86_64.jar" />
</resources>

<resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">   
    <jar href="swt-win32-windows-x86_64.jar" />
</resources>

<resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="swt-gtk-linux-x86_64.jar" />
</resources>

<resources os="Linux" arch="amd64">
    <jar href="swt-gtk-linux-x86_64.jar" />
</resources>

<resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
    <jar href="swt-gtk-linux-x86.jar" />
</resources>

<resources os="Mac" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="swt-cocoa-mac-x86_64.jar" />
</resources>

<resources os="Mac" arch="amd64">
    <jar href="swt-cocoa-mac-x86_64.jar" />
</resources>

<resources os="Mac" arch="x86">
    <jar href="swt-cocoa-mac-x86.jar" />
</resources>

<application-desc main-class="com.game.Main"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Privet, see my answer and try step 1. Once you get the jnlp file right according to JaNeLa, publish stacktrace where application startup fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use [JaNeLa](http://pscode.org/janela/) by Andrew Thomphson to verify your jnlp file.

2) `<java version="1.5" />`

might need to change to

```
<j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
```

it is in every tutorial.

3) `<nativelib href="jl1.0.1.jar" download="eager"/>`

I am not sure, but I think `nativelib` is for C libraries, try changing it to `jar`

`download="eager"` is default value, so it is meaningless to specify

4) "so should I generate runnable jar file with eclipse with all the libs packaged inside the jar"

No, this is not the way jnlp applets supposed to be deployed.

[JNLP File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)

[Deploying a Java Web Start Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html)

Comment: +1 for your answer.  Note re. point 3) Well spotted, and I also think most of the Jars in the OS/architecture specific resources elements **should be** `nativelib` rather than `jar` - for the same reason.

Comment: By using Janela, I got my App to start at least on windows so far

Comment: By using Janela, I got my App to start at least on windows so far (test linux tomorrow). the only problem is now that application appears not at at the center of the screen and slightly different in size 31 pixel shorter in width compared to the original one(i generated the jars at the same time, so there is no source code difference) when starting from jnlp .I don't now if its a bug or something else .Sometimes my app starts at the center, sometimes it starts fullscreen. Anyway  thanks Nikolay for the suggestions and thanks a lot @Andrew for such a great tool!